# Do failed audits affect the frequency of audits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I have been doing a lot of reviewing over the past several months, and I honestly try to do it to the best of my ability.  It's happened four or five times that I've failed an audit.  Sometimes I disagree with the result, sometimes I feel like it's a border case so I should have skipped, sometimes it's just a mistake.  I tell myself it's inevitable when doing a lot of reviews, though it's a pretty low feeling, especially due to the wording of the audit.

I had a streak of a good 50 review questions without an audit, but then was audited - and failed.  I wondered if it was due to the fact that I'd passed the last ten or so times I was audited.  And if so, if I would be audited more often in future.  Lo and behold, I was hit with more audits after that failed one.

Is this confirmation bias, or does passing/failing audits affect the frequency with which you get audited?

Comment: Yes, see [Stop bothering me with suggested edit review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183017)

Answer (score 22):

Yes, how well you do on audits affects the frequency at which you are being given audits in the future. See [Stop bothering me with suggested edit review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182722/stop-bothering-me-with-suggested-edit-review-audits/183017#183017):

> - 100% success rate for, say, the past 20 audits gets you at least 30 reviews before the next one,
> - Anything under 50% rolls the dice every review.

Shog9 was speculating on the rules for audit frequencies in that post, but that was exactly what was implemented.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, that makes sense!  Just out of curiosity, what are the chances on "rolling the dice"? (If that isn't privileged information, of course!)

Comment: I don't know. 50/50 chance you get a review, I guess.

Comment: Does 'skip' count as a review in this context?

Comment: @TZHX: for audits, you mean? No 'pass' or 'fail' is recorded for skipped audits, so they don't count towards the success rate.

Comment: @TZHX but if you skip a lot (I sometimes do that in the CVQ) you get more audits...