# Why does the close votes review queue have so many audits?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits

I just reached 3k reputation. So, I just started to review [Reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats) and [Close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats).

Especially while reviewing in close votes, I did a lot of review audits. I'm actually at 16 reviews, and I made 3 review audits. Comparing to another review queue, in [First question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/stats), each day I made between 2 and 5 audits for 80 reviews!

At this frequency, it represents 16.7% of all review tasks which seems to be a lot.

Here are all the reviews that I actually made, and review audits are with red lines.

[image]

Is that normal? Why does this review queue have so many review audits?

Update: now it's each 3 close votes? Is that a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be solved now, maybe a lack of luck at the time of reviewing.

Answer (score 6):

Audit frequency depends on your [pass/fail rate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/301027/1038015).

- the more audits you pass, the fewer audits you'll see
- conversely the more audits you fail the more audits you'll see

The system just doesn't know what you're like yet and of course there's [clumping in randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_illusion) that humans just don't really get intuitively. In addition [one swallow does not a summer make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdotal_evidence), so we can't generalise audit frequency from a single case i.e. yours.

Note that a [single audit failure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) is not enough to cause you to be banned.

Comment: When I was at 16 review (and 3 audits) I pass only 3 posts. Also, If I fail one audit I will just be banned, there isn't any audit failed counter that just let you show more audit if you already first one

Comment: I didn't failed audit since this morning while reviewing first question, so why I have a lot of more review audit ?

Comment: That's also why I ask if it was normal. I read, a day, that it was waiting at least some review before possibly show audit, and this doesn't seems to be done if I receive audit each 5 (or more recently each 3) review

Comment: I'm aware of one reviewer who does a lot of (good, may I add) reviews, and passes every audit. Their previous fail was in 2018, and they received almost 10 audits on the fourth alone. I'm sure the claim applies on paper, but I'm not sure if that's the reality anymore. Not sure why. I blame the audit system in general. Could be a bug, could be intentional, could never have applied to begin with; and I doubt we'll ever find out

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Well it begs the question what the minimum is. I'm sure if you caused it to go up, it can also go down again. But I'm also sure the amount of audits you gets does not bottom out at 0.

Comment: @Gimby Even if it doesn't bottom out at 0, why would it go back up, and more importantly, why that high? All the audits were in the same queue on the same day, in the same "review quota" (i.e. not done before and after midnight UTC). Skyrocketing that high for no obvious reason does scream of bug and/or broken to me at least. Weird situation anyway

Comment: @Zoe Granted, 10 audits is pretty overzealous.

Comment: When you're new in the queue, the system acts as if you have failed an audit. / cc @Elikill58

Comment: @rene I was thinking about this, I just didn't found staff's answer that confirm it, but I agree with you, thanks :)